# iTextSharp return ' \n' instead of '\n'

Tags: itext

Manipulating PDF files I found that reading the iTextSharp (version 5.4.5.0) through the same program files being read by another tool like Aspose.Pdf, the result of Aspose is more accurate when it comes to breaking lines.

Some lines read by iTextSharp instead of returning `'\n'` (enter) it returns `' \n'` (newline due to the character limit per line - that should be replaced by one space).

My code:

```
PdfReader pdfreader = new PdfReader(pathNmArq);
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
extractText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfreader, page, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
```

Example:

```
iTextSharp: "\n3ª Camara \nApelação 0713141\n"

Aspose.Pdf: "\n3ª Camara\nApelação 0713141\n"
```

Does anyone know why iTextSharp misinterpreting this? 
How can I avoid this?

PS: The tool Aspose.Pdf somewhat expensive (not free)

Comment: Please show the code that you are using for text extraction. Also, what version of iTextSharp?

Comment: Hi, thanks. My version is 5.4.5.0. Extraction:  ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();   extractText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfreader, page, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());

Comment: `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` does not generate the spaces out of thin air, they are there. It does add the line break characters, though.

Comment: Btw, you instantiate a `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` but don't use it. Is There any reason for that. Furthermore, to analyze *why iTextSharp misinterpreting this* Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: Also note that, for reasons of accessibility, the ISO standard encourages to add a space at the end of the line before the newline.